# Help with LINQ query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do this with LINQ:

```
SQL>>    SELECT p_Id from items WHERE p_Name = 'R1'


LINQ>>   var getpID = (from p in myDatabaseDataSet.Items
                         where p.p_Name == ptxtBox.Text
                         select p.p_Id).SingleOrDefault();

            int p_Id = getpID;
```

But getpID always return 0. What's wrong?.

Edit: nvm the syntax is correct. Reason why it always returned 0 is the value doesn't exist in the db. I had the txt box value inserted in the db and then was trying to call it again before refreshing myDatabaseSet. So I needed to add Fill() and then getpID is able to read the value.

Full code:

```
        int c_Id = Convert.ToInt32(pcomboBox.SelectedValue);

        int p_Id = 0;
        string itemName = ptxtBox.Text;


        this.Validate();
        this.itemsBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.itemsTableAdapter.Insert(c_Id, itemName);
        this.myDatabaseDataSet.AcceptChanges();
        this.itemsTableAdapter.Fill(myDatabaseDataSet.Items);


            var getpID = (from p in myDatabaseDataSet.Items
                          where p.p_Name == itemName
                          select p.p_Id).SingleOrDefault();

            p_Id = getpID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494540(v=VS.90).aspx) use [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358452(v=VS.90).aspx)

In case of the resulting sequence having multiple values `SingleOrDefault()` will fail to behave as you want, where are `FirstOrDefault()` will work.

Comment: Actually if the sequence has multiple values, SingleOrDefault will throw an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 1):

[`SingleOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) -

> Returns the only element of a
>   sequence, or a default value if the
>   sequence is empty;

It seems that your collection is empty(default if int is 0), check the `ptxtBox.Text` value